# Insert image into MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, filechooser

I am doing create product using netbeans and mySQL. I used a file chooser to get the image from user when button is on click, for example:

```
public void handle(ActionEvent event){
     FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

        //Set extension filter
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterJPG = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPG files (*.jpg)", "*.JPG");
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterPNG = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PNG files (*.png)", "*.PNG");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(extFilterJPG, extFilterPNG);

        //Show open file dialog
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        try {
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
            WritableImage image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
            myImageView.setImage(image);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CreateProductUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
```

And I display the image using code below:

```
Image image = panel.getMyImageView().getImage();
```

It works fine until I try to insert the image into database. This is my constructor and create method:

```
public Product(String name,String desc,double price, int quantity,String datestr,Image image){
    this.name = name;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.price = price;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.datestr = datestr;
    this.image = image;
}

public boolean create(){
    boolean success = false;
    DBController db = new DBController();
    String dbQuery; 
    db.getConnection();     

    dbQuery = "INSERT INTO sm_product(productName,productDescription,productPrice,productQuantity,dateOfCreation,productStatus,productImage) VALUES ('" + name + "', '" + desc + "', " + price + ", " + quantity + ",'" + datestr + "', 'Available', '" + image + "')";

    if (db.updateRequest(dbQuery) == 1){
        success = true;
    }
    db.terminate();
    return success;
}
```

However, the image was stored as 'javafx.scene.image.WritableImage@3a6e48b3'. I tried twice with the same image but the address was different. I wonder am I storing image in a wrong way? I not sure whether I can retrieve the image using select SQL statement because I have not try yet but I think it does not work.

Anybody has a better way to solve it because the image stored in database is very weird which I think it might be wrong.

Thanks in advance.

**Updated portion**

```
public void getConnection(){ 
    String url = ""; 
    try { 
        //url = "jdbc:mysql://172.20.133.227/test"; 
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/amkcc"; 
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "root"); 
        System.out.println("Successfully connected to " + url+ "."); 
    } 
    catch (java.sql.SQLException e) { 
        System.out.println("Connection failed ->"+ url); 
        System.out.println(e); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: to store the blob you need to pass a `byte[]` as the parameter. you will need to figure out how to construct that from your existing code

Comment: what is blob? also how to use a byte[]

Comment: if you use a bit of google i am sure you can find the answers.

Comment: @DevZer0 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/blob.html. I'd found this. But still, I am lost

Answer (score -1):

An example of how to save images in MySQL using JDBC:

```
File image = new File("C:/image.jpg");
psmnt = connection.prepareStatement
  ("insert into save_image(name, city, image, Phone) "+ "values(?,?,?,?)");
psmnt.setString(1,"MyName");
psmnt.setString(2,"MyCity");
psmnt.setString(4,"123456");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image);
psmnt.setBinaryStream(3, (InputStream)fis, (int)(image.length()));
int s = psmnt.executeUpdate();
```

This is how your method should look like:

```
public boolean create(){
 boolean success = false;
 try{
 DBController db = new DBController();
 String dbQuery; 
 db.getConnection();     

 dbQuery = "INSERT INTO sm_product(productName,productDescription,productPrice,productQuantity,dateOfCreation,productStatus,productImage) VALUES (?,?,?,?, ?, 'Available', ?)";

 PreparedStatement psmnt = db.getConnection().prepareStatement(dbQuery);
 psmnt.setString(1,name);
 psmnt.setString(2, desc);
 psmnt.setDouble(3, price);
 psmnt.setInt(4, quantity);
 psmnt.setString(5, dateStr);

 File imageFile = new File("test.png");
 RenderedImage renderedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);
 ImageIO.write(renderedImage, "png", imageFile); //Change extension appropriately
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
 psmnt.setBinaryStream(3, (InputStream)fis, (int)(imageFile.length()));
 int s = psmnt.executeUpdate();

 //check the value of s and initialize success appropriately

 return success;
 }catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
   return false;

}
```

The `getConnection()` method in 'DBController` should be like this:

```
public Connection getConnection(){ 
            if(con != null) return con;
    String url = ""; 
    try { 
        //url = "jdbc:mysql://172.20.133.227/test"; 
        url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/amkcc"; 
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "root"); 
        System.out.println("Successfully connected to " + url+ "."); 
                    return con;
    } 
    catch (java.sql.SQLException e) { 
        System.out.println("Connection failed ->"+ url); 
        System.out.println(e); 
    } 
            return null;
}
```

Comment: But I am getting file from user input so I do not know the exact location for image.

Comment: It's not me downvoting by the way. My votes are still not enough. It's by some other user. What's your connection class does? Thanks

Comment: true, I didn't realize that. By the way, the `connection` object should be retrieved from your `DBController` class, probably something like `db.getConnection()`

Comment: I got unreported exception SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown error message. And there are red lines everywhere. I guess something went wrong in my DBController?

Comment: You should enclose few things in try-catch block. Its good if you learn about Exceptions before going further. Updated the code.

Comment: I still got an error message "void cannot be dereferenced" at the PreparedStatement psmnt = db.getConnection().prepareStatement(dbQuery); and "cannot find symbol" at the setInteger

Comment: `setInteger` should be `setInt` and make sure that your `getConnection()` method of `DBController` returns the `Connection` object

Comment: But the PreparedStatement still cannot be dereferenced

Comment: What is the signature of `getConnection()` method in `DBController` class?

Comment: Updated the answer, but seems like you have a lot to learn in Java before doing this kind of stuff

Comment: Okay thanks but there's whole bunch of error when inserting. Does your code apply to any images chosen by user? Because I saw your "test.png" and I thought it's only fix to the image called test.png

Comment: What data type should I put for image column? Because if I put varchar, it told me an error message about wrong input string and it doesn't works for other data types as well. And I hopefully that you will explain a little bit of your codes. Thanks.

Comment: It should be `blob` type. An example `CREATE TABLE imagedb(             
              id int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,  
              name varchar(25) default NULL,      
              image blob                       
 );`

Comment: But it's stored as Blob in database. I can't see any location of that image like wallpaper.jpg. Am I able to simply retrieve using Select SQL statement?

Comment: Data truncation means that the data you are trying to insert is bigger than the size of the column that you have declared in you database. Check in the stacktrace for which column you are getting that error. What is the exact error message?

Comment: Now it's fixed but whenever I try to create a new product, the program just keep running without ending. For example, it supposed to printout the sql statement after successfully insert into table, but my one just keep showing jfxsa-run running but it's inserted into table already